# Stop and Cat function in R with greek letter

Tags: r

I am wondering why cat function print the greek letter in R but when I use in stop function it doesn't look like greek letter

Here is the code

```
al1 <- paste0(intToUtf8(945),1,sep='')
al2 <- paste0(intToUtf8(945),2,sep='')
msg <- paste0(al2," must be between 0 and ",al1)
stop(msg)
Error: a2 must be between 0 and a1
cat(msg)
α2 must be between 0 and α1
```

You can see in stop it look like "a"?

Here is the sessioninfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You may need to add information about your R version, platform and locale (via `sessionInfo()`).

Comment: I can reproduce, R 3.4.0. Weirdly: `stop(intToUtf8(945)) > Error: a`, `stop(intToUtf8(946)) > Error: ß`, `stop(intToUtf8(947))
Error: <U+03B3>`. So behaviour seems to vary quite a bit.

Comment: For reference, I'm on R 3.4.3, macOS 10.12.5 and the usual en_US.UTF-8 locale.

Comment: @joran added the session info